# Symfony2 service where put abstract manager

Tags: file, service, symfony

I want to practise using services in Symfony2.

To practise I want to implement an abstract base UserManager (CRUD).

My question is now where I put these files (UserManager, UserManagerInterface, ...)

The FOSUserBundle puts these files into the Model-Dir but in my opinion the userManager belongs to the logical layer.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call them `UserService`, `ArticleService`, etc, after the [Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) pattern and put them under the `Service` folder of a bundle.